# Как подсчитать количество нулей на конце числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм решения данной задачи.

```
def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(end_zeros(0))

    assert end_zeros(0) == 1
    assert end_zeros(1) == 0
    assert end_zeros(10) == 1
    assert end_zeros(101) == 0
    assert end_zeros(245) == 0
    assert end_zeros(100100) == 2
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

Comment: Два подхода: 1 - преобразовать число в строку, потом идти циклом от конца строки и считать символы `'0'`. 2 - в цикле делить число на 10, считать сколько раз поделится делится без остатка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Будём считать количество нулей следующим образом: *Если число делится на 10, то делить его и увеличивать значение переменной countZero - иначе нету смысла искать нули, их попросту нет)*

**По правилу делимости на 10 следует, что если число оканчивается на "0" то число делится на "10"**.

Краткое решение на python:

```
n = int(input())

if (n == 0): 
    print(1)
    exit()

countZero = 0
while (n % 10 == 0):
    n //= 10
    countZero += 1

print(countZero)
```

Comment: И еще один вопрос, касаемо целочисленного деления в цикле while. Подскажите как он работает, то есть он отбрасывает числа с конца, но не понятно как это работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Деление на 10 отбрасывает один знак справа. Это арифметика.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    return len(str(num)) - len(str(num).rstrip('0'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(end_zeros(0))

    assert end_zeros(0) == 1
    assert end_zeros(1) == 0
    assert end_zeros(10) == 1
    assert end_zeros(101) == 0
    assert end_zeros(245) == 0
    assert end_zeros(100100) == 2
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

Comment: Круто! Хорошо, что питон позволяет много способов сделать одно и то же )

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант однострочник просто по приколу. Тесты из условия проходит, но работает не оптимально, конечно:

```
def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    return min((i for i,c in enumerate(str(num)[::-1], 0) if c != '0'), default=1)
```

Это по алгоритму "преобразовать число в строку, потом идти циклом от конца строки и считать символы '0'", указанному insolor.

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```
def end_zeros(n):
    return 0 if n%10 else 1+(end_zeros(n//10) if n else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, и без деления.

```
def countendszero(number):
    number = str(number)
    i = len(number) - 1
    r = 0
    while i >= 0 :
        digit = number[i]
        if digit == "0" :
            r += 1
        else :
            break
        i -= 1
    return r

print(countendszero(100))
# 2
```