# задача создать функцию , которая принимает неотрицательное число, находит его факториал и возвращает сколько нулей на конце этого факториала

Tags: python, факториал

```
def factorial(n: int):
    a = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        a*=i
        return(a)

def trailing_zeros(n: int) -> int:
    f = factorial(n)
    f_list=list(f)
    f_list.reverse()
    count=0
    for i in range(f_list):
        if i ==0:
            count+=1
            break
            return count
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы.

Comment: Факториал можно найти функцией factorial() из модуля math. Если это нельзя использовать, то просто нужно перемножить числа от 1 до n, взяв за исключение, что 0!=1. Количество нулей можно просто посчитать циклом, в чем проблема?

Comment: ежели вам нужен чистый питон, то так и скажите, а то другие люди стараются для вас, а вы даже не помечаете ответ как правильный

Comment: Вопрос в том что код не работает, задачка на степике, нужен чистый питон

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: https://stepik.org/lesson/296972/step/8?unit=278700

Comment: Кто-нибудь, у кого есть доступ. В задаче требуется считать факториал? Или требуется только считать нули в этом факториале (а сам факториал не нужен)?

Comment: Найти факториал, а потом делить его на 10, на каждом шаге запоминая число шагов, до тех пор пока в результате не будет 0.х десятых. Затем вернуть число шагов - 1.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну как хотите)) Я вам ответ написал.

Comment: @Максим зарегистрировался. ответ с двумя функциями принимает. смотрите ниже

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy исправил ответ

Comment: Перестаньте писать ему как посчитать факториал. В этой задаче значение факториала не нужно.

Comment: @Igor нужен. черным по белому же написано в самом задании - "создать функцию, которая принимает неотрицательное число, находит его факториал и возвращает сколько нулей на конце этого факториала". специально ж залез и зарегистрировался.

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов Не нужен. Как, интересно, проверяющий код узнает, вычисляли Вы факториал или нет?

Comment: @Igor а для чего, интересно, даны две функции на вход. одна из которых предназначена для вычисления факториала?

Comment: Сначала нужно написать функцию факториала, затем написать функцию которая считает нули от числа факториала

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:** С использованием *numpy* и *re*.

Находим факториал и количество нулей в конце через  *re.search*

```
import numpy as np
import re

def zeros(n: int):
    fact = np.math.factorial(n)
    return len(re.search('(0*)$', str(fact)).group(0))
```

**Вариант 2 (Нашел у @CrazyElf):**
(добавил лишь нахождение факториала)

```
def end_zeros(n: int) -> int:
    num = np.math.factorial(n)
    return min((i for i,c in enumerate(str(num)[::-1], 0) if c != '0'), default=1)
```

ссылка на его решение:
[ответ @CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1178086/385765)

**UPD. Вариант 3 (без использования библиотек):**

P.S. Пришлось зарегистрироваться на сайте и поступить на курс (Этот ответ принимает система)

```
def factorial(n: int):
    a = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        a *=i
    return a

def trailing_zeros(n: int) -> int:    
    list_of = list(str(factorial(n)))
    count = 0
    for i in list_of[::-1]:
        if i == '0':
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count
```

**UPD 2. Вариант 4. (Вообще без нахождения факториала)**

Суть в том, что нам можно не находить сам факториал числа *n*, чтобы знать сколько там нулей.

поэтому мы можем в функцию просто передать число, от которого нужно найти факториал и получить количество нулей, что при больших числах будет намного быстрее.

```
def factorial(n):
    count = 0
    while n >=5:
        n //= 5
        count += n
    return count
```

Comment: Ну я же там написал, что это моё решение по приколу чисто, оно не оптимальное и не очень понятное )

Comment: я не читал, что там написано, но бывает, грешу однострочными решениями, поэтому выбрал его, как самое близкое по духу ))) а первый вариант -  моя интерпретация

Answer (score 1):

Вызовем вашу функцию `factorial`:

> ```
> factorial(1) = 1
> factorial(2) = 1
> factorial(3) = 1
> factorial(4) = 1
> factorial(5) = 1
> factorial(6) = 1
> factorial(7) = 1
> factorial(8) = 1
> factorial(9) = 1
> factorial(10) = 1
> ```

Очевидно функция `factorial` не считает факториал. Исправим ошибку и пойдём дальше. На этот раз вычислим `trailing_zeros(1)`:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
>     print(f'trailing_zeros({i}) = {trailing_zeros(i)}')
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 9, in trailing_zeros
>     f_list=list(f)
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Ошибка состоит в вызове функции `list` от числа. Это запрещено в Питоне.

Рекомендую вам запустить и привести в чувство вашу программу на компьютере прежде чем посылать в Степик на проверку.

**P.S.** Эта задача решается по-другому, без вычисления факториала.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

n = int(input())
result = sum(n // 5**i for i in range(1, int(math.log(n, 5))+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    f_list=list(f)
    ...
    for i in range(f_list):
        if i ==0:
            count+=1
            break
            return count
```

1. Делайте из числа не список (как это вообще?), а строку.
2. Перебирать нужно саму строку, а не `range` от неё (и `range` от списка тоже бессмысленен)
3. Строку нужно сравнивать со строкой `== '0'`
4. Прерывать цикл с помощью `break` нужно не когда встретился `'0'`, а наоборот, когда не встретился.
5. `return` нужно делать в самом конце, уже после цикла, ибо `0` может и сразу не встретиться (у вас лишние отступы)

Comment: выдает во т такую ошибкуError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 14, in <module>
    assert trailing_zeros(0) == 0
  File "jailed_code", line 8, in trailing_zeros
    f_list=list(f)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable